# Apache SOLR multiple value (price) for an item implementing dynamic filter

Tags: solr, schema, jsonschema

I'm looking for **Schema** that is performant to have multiple store price for a product. Tried the following schema, but wondering if any better idea to make this performant, the one tried as follows. I'm ready to duplicate these data just to make this performant.

**Open for elastic schema as well.**

**TRY1 - Document Nested**

```
{
  "sku" : "123",
  "prices" : {
    "store_1" : 10.2,
    "store_2" : 12.2,
    "store_3" : 11.2
  }
}
```

The above works fine, but introducing nested will have worse performance.

**TRY2 - Document flat map**

```
{
  "sku" : "123",
    "store_1" : 10.2,
    "store_2" : 12.2,
    "store_3" : 11.2
}
```

I have limitation on how many fields I can create.

It sounds like broad question, but looking for some hacks to make this performant, also added my tries, I spent alot of time on these. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What does "more performant" mean (i.e. what's the problem with your current solution)? What are you trying to achieve? Why is the current solution too slow? What are you trying to achieve with these fields - only filtering against price in some way ("price for the product in _a_ store is between x and y") or per store filtering ("store x has this product for sale between x and y") or "these stores have the product available for sale between price x and y"? All these will have different requirements for how you index the data.